# Button triggering surrounding buttons not working properly

Tags: javascript, html

I have this javascript code:

```
function toggle(i,j) {
  b=document.getElementById("but_" + i + j)
  t = b.innerHTML
  if (t=="X") {b.innerHTML = "O";
               b.setAttribute( "style", "color:red; background-color:yellow" )
              }
  if (t=="O") {b.innerHTML = "X";
               b.setAttribute( "style", "color:white; background-color:black" )
              }
}

function press(i, j) {
toggle(i, j);
toggle(i-1, j);
toggle(i+1, j);
toggle(i, j-1);
toggle(i, j+1);
}



function generateGrid() {
    var d = document.getElementById("button-grid");
    var table = document.createElement("table");
    d.appendChild(table);
    for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
            var row = document.createElement("tr");
            for (var j = 0; j < 5; j++) {
                    var cell = document.createElement("td");
                    cell.innerHTML = "<button type=button id=but_" + i + j +
                                     " onclick=\"press(" +i + ',' +j + ")\"" + 
                                     " style=\"color:red; background-color:yellow\"" +
                                     ">O</button>" ;
                    row.appendChild(cell);
            }
            table.appendChild(row);
    }
    toggle(2,2) // Set middle button to off state (otherwise it seems to be impossible).
}

window.onload = function() {
    generateGrid();
};
```

I want it that when I click a button on the grid, it toggles not only that button, but also the top, bottom, left and right buttons too.

It works using this code for all buttons except for when you toggle one the buttons on the edge. I need it so for example, when you click a button on the right hand side edge, it toggles itself along with the top, bottom and left buttons.

If you need any more information please let me know, thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would have to add an if statement to check if the button is on the edge - for example, you can use:

```
if (i > 0) {
    toggle(i-1, j);
}
if (i < 4) {
    toggle(i+1, j);
}
if (j > 0) {
    toggle(i, j-1);
}
if (j < 4) {
    toggle(i, j+1);
}
```

This way, it will only toggle the button i-1 (the button to the left) only if the button isn't on the left column, or if i = 0.